# Response object has no attribute encoding, scrapy error

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am getting this error in scrapy

```
   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/selector/factories.py", line 20, in body_as_utf8
   if response.encoding in utf8_encodings:
   exceptions.AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'encoding'
```

The code that causes it is just the following in a scrapy spider

```
 def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
```

I am trying to parse the url

```
    http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/customerReviews?id=382034404%0A
```

with the user agent string

```
   iTunes/10.2 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X 10.2)
```

Any idea what could be the error? it seems strange to me, this code always work in all my other spiders

Answer (score 4):

I don't have time to debug it, but my guess is that the `response` argument in this particular case is not a `HtmlResponse`or `TextResponse`.

In the callback do `print response.__class__`

If the class is `scrapy.http.response.Response`, then my guess it that the url returns a non text response, which obviously is byte stream without any `encoding`, and you cannot use xpath on it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is super helpful but maybe it can help guide you or someone else.

I was getting a similar error:

> 'Response' object has no attribute 'elapsed'

It was resolved by updating the `requests` dependency:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install --upgrade requests
```

So maybe you have a dependency that provides the attribute `encoding`?

Answer (score 0):

try this way please:

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(text=response.body)
```